# Visual Basic Express project is not (always) saved on disk

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I'm a Visual Basic newbie, doing a quick'n'dirty VB app in Visual Studio 2010 Express (under Windows 7, 64-bit).

I save constantly. I have used the "Save All" option. I have rebuilt the app.
Still, the project is not always written to disk when I save! (sometimes, my changes are written to disk, but I haven't found out yet the pattern). This is really bugging me, since quite a few times I saved my project, closed VB, and then I realized all my changes had not been saved.

Is this some limitation of VB Express? I am using Visual C++ Express, too, and I had no such problems there.

**EDIT: For even more clarification -- I am not getting any errors, and I am not having problems with version control. What I do is:**

1. I make changes in source file.
2. I press save.
3. I rebuild, at a certain time hh:mm.
4. I look on the disk, and **sometimes** my source file's "last modified time" is not hh:mm, and if I open it, the changes from 1) are not in the source file. Sometimes it is there, but I can't say for sure when or why.

The config on my machine is nothing special as far as I know, just normal Windows 7, 64-bit. I guess if it were some access rights related issue, the saving would never happen, instead of what I'm experiencing now.
By now, I think one can safely assume that this is no Visual Studio Express issue (just installed it as it came, using it "out of the box").

Comment: do yourself a favour, and use a source code revision control system

Comment: @Mitch I am using svn, but since the project is not saved on disk, "svn status" doesn't find any changes :)

Comment: are you saving to a local drive?

Comment: Yes, a normal path like "c:\workspace\project".

Comment: Does this happen too when you work _without_ source control?

Comment: Everything is saved when you build.  Build often.  The IDE won't let you close it without prompting you to save.  There's something else going on if you find out that changes didn't get saved.

Comment: @Sascha: source control has nothing to do with it -- the modifications in the editor are not saved to the disk when I press Save.

Comment: @Hans I have saved and rebuilt, but the modifications appear on the disk sometimes after an hour or so. Weird behaviour, I know! Even funnier: added a new source code file (Module? in VB lingo), in the form's properties it says location on disk is "c:\workspace\project" (correct, it is where my project is located), everything is saved and built and whatnot, and in "c:\workspace\project" there is no module file! Appears if I'm lucky, sometimes asap, sometimes after a random amount of time.

Comment: You need to get your machine fixed.  Ask questions about this disk behavior at superuser.com

Comment: Thanks all for commenting, at least now I know that it's not a Visual Studio issue.